# Finding variational equation and a explicit expression for it

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Since this is my first encounter with ODE's so I'm not really used to the way of the problems are presented and It's getting pretty hard to get used to it. So, I come here to give me your enlightenment over a subject Im not understanding.

**Problem**

$\dot y = ty^{2}, y(0)=1$ the its solution function $\phi(t,x)=y(t)$. Find the variational equations for $\partial _{x}\phi(t,x)$ and $\partial^{2}_{x} \phi(t,x)$ and find a explicit expression for $\partial^{2}_{x} \phi(t,x)$.

Thanks so much for your help, and the book im using to study is ODE and Dynamical System, G.Teschl. If you have better books to recommend please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at equations (2.49) and (2.51) in Teschl. A variational equation for $(\partial_x)^n \phi(t,x)$ is given by

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\partial_x)^n \phi(t,x) = (\partial_x)^n f(t,\phi(t,x))$$

which will eventually simplify down to a linear ODE for $(\partial_x)^n \phi(t,x)$ by the chain rule. Lets look at this problem as an example. The first variational equation is given by

$$\partial_t (\partial_x \phi) = \partial_x(\partial_t \phi) = \partial_x(t \phi^2) = 2t\phi(\partial_x\phi)$$

linear in $\partial_x\phi$, as advertised. The second variational equation would be

$$\partial_t (\partial_x^2 \phi) = \partial_x^2 (\partial_t \phi) = \partial_x^2 (t\phi^2) = 2t(\partial_x \phi)^2 + 2t\phi(\partial_x^2 \phi)$$

This becomes solving an inhomogeneous first order linear equation. First solve the homogeneous part:

$$\partial_t u = 2t\phi u \implies u = C\exp\left(\int_0^t 2t\phi dt \right) = C\exp\left(\int_0^t 2\frac{\partial_t \phi}{\phi} dt \right) = C\phi^2$$

Then use variation of parameters (i.e. substitute in $vu$ where $u$ was the solution to our homogeneous equation) to solve the inhomogeneous part:

$$(\partial_t v)u = 2t(\partial_x \phi)^2 \implies v = \int_0^t \frac{2t(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^2}dt = \int_0^t \frac{(\partial_x \phi)\partial_t (\partial_x \phi)}{\phi^3}dt$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^3}\Biggr|_0^t + \frac{3}{2}\int_0^t \frac{(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^4}\partial_t \phi dt = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}\int_0^t \frac{2t(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^2} dt$$

$$\implies v = \frac{2(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi^3} - 2$$

where we used the fact that $\phi(0,x) = x \implies \partial_x \phi(0,x) = 1$ (in our case $x=1$, too). Thus we have

$$\partial_x^2 \phi = C\phi^2 + \frac{2(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi}$$

Plugging in our initial condition $\partial_x^2 \phi(0,x) = 0$ (obtained by differentiating the expression above):

$$\partial_x^2 \phi = \frac{2(\partial_x \phi)^2}{\phi} - 2\phi^2$$

which may be as far as we can go. Or...

We can solve for $\partial_x \phi$ from the first variational equation. We already solved this equation, it was the homogeneous equation from earlier. That means

$$\partial_x \phi = C\phi^2 = \phi^2$$

where we used the initial condition in the second equality. Plugging into the expression for the second derivative yields:

$$\partial_x^2 \phi = 2\phi^3 - 2\phi^2 = 2\phi^2(\phi - 1)$$

If I made any mistakes in my integration please let me know, it was a little late when I wrote this.

Comment: Thanks so much sir, you made everything incredibly clear <3

Comment: @asd123 You're very welcome! When I was learning ODE, my instructor only used this book as a reference for the material in the later chapters. We first started off with the book by Perko if you want to read that instead. If you feel ready after that, come back to this book and have go at Arnold's book.